# C# Asp.Net MVC - Combine Select Lists?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, selectlist

I have these two methods below. One returns a list of manufacturers based on the handset ID and the other returns a list of Handsets based on the Handset ID (relationship via handset ID). How can I combine them to return one select list with the combined manufacturer handset value?
(Bit new to MVC)

```
SelectList GetManufacturers()
{
        var manufacturers = ((DataPage<Manufacturer>)ViewData["Manufacturers"]).Records;
        return new SelectList(manufacturers, "ID", "Name", ViewData.Model.HandsetID != null ? ViewData.Model.HandsetID : -1);
}

SelectList GetHandsets()
{
    var list = ((DataPage<Handset>)ViewData["Handsets"]).Records;
    return new SelectList(list, "ID", "Name", ViewData.Model.HandsetID != null ? ViewData.Model.HandsetID : -1);
}
```

Help greatly appreciated,

Kind regards

Comment: It appears you're doing this on the View (though I could be wrong and you're using viewdata to pass stuff between functions). If so, don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work.  It performs an inner join on your two lists, and then concatenates the manufacturer name and handset names of each record, with a space in between.

```
var manufacturers = ((DataPage<Manufacturer>)ViewData["Manufacturers"]).Records;
var handsets = ((DataPage<Handset>)ViewData["Handsets"]).Records;

var list = 

     from manufacturer in manufacturers
     join handset in handsets on manufacturer.HandsetID equals handset.HandsetID
     select new 
     { 
         ID = handset.HandsetID,
         Name = manufacturer.Name + " " + handset.Name
     };
return new SelectList(list, "ID", "Name", ViewData.Model.HandsetID != null ? ViewData.Model.HandsetID : -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is from a database, you should concatenate both fields (Manufacturer and Handset).

In linqtosql this goes like:

```
var result = (from foo in db.foos 
                 select new {
                             ID = foo.ID
                             Name = foo.Manufacturer + " " + foo.Handheld,
                            });
```

You can then use the result to fill your selectlist